# Toggle the State of a CKEditor plugin button

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

What is the correct way to toggle the state of a ckeditor plugin menu button based on the selection?

For example, in a link/unlink plugin, I would only want to enable unlink if the cursor is in a link.

```
editor.addCommand("unlink", {
    exec: function (editor) {
         //do something here
    },
    refresh: function (editor, path) {
       // never seems to get fired. Is this even the right hook?
    }
});

editor.ui.addButton("Unlink", {
    label: "Unlink",
    command: "unlink"
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

There is [`CKEDITOR.commandDefinition#contextSensitive`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.commandDefinition-property-contextSensitive) property that makes it possible to control the state of a command in a particular context.

For example, the [actual implementation](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/ccd0038ca5512dbafbb975dd7ec5444ff47f7767/plugins/link/plugin.js#L704-L725) of Unlink button looks like:

```
CKEDITOR.unlinkCommand.prototype = {
    exec: function( editor ) {
        ...
    },

    refresh: function( editor, path ) {     
        var element = path.lastElement && path.lastElement.getAscendant( 'a', true );

        if ( element && element.getName() == 'a' && element.getAttribute( 'href' ) && element.getChildCount() )
            this.setState( CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF );
        else
            this.setState( CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED );
    },

    contextSensitive: 1,
    ...
};
```

Comment: I tried to use this method as showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991766/1941316) and noticed some refresh issues. Would you know why the refresh is not always done?